# Why do I get "Unknown element 'pagination' or...." angular/ui.bootstrap pagination

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using pagination (angular/ui.bootstrap) for my list. The pagination control shows on my site but in VS it says "Unknown element 'pagination' or element cannot be placed here". https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIEl2.png

I've placed the pagination tag right after my table (ng-repeat), and inside my ng-controller div.

I'm using thsese cdns

- ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js
- angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js
- netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

EDIT: Dont know why, but it works even if VS throws an warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is Angular Custom Directive, so VS will think that it's not a valid element.

Looking at the angular-ui source code, pagination accept restrict 'EA'. So if you really don't want to see the warning, you can try to do something like this :

`<div data-pagination></div>`

For more info about restrict option:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thank you, that's correct. It works when adding data-.